# HTMLPurifier ignoring attributes even though in config

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I'm having trouble allowing certain HTML attributes into HTMLPurifier's whitelist.

This is my code:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'u,p,b,i,span[style],strike,s,strong,em,li,ul,ol,div[align],br,img[src|alt|width|height],sub,sup');
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

When I run: `$clean_str = $purifier->purify($dirty_str);` on this: `<div align="left">Left</div>` I get this: `<div>left</div>`.

If I remove: `div[align]` from `HTML.Allowed` I get this: `Left` - so I know that the `HTML.Allowed` is working for elements, but not for attributes.

I'm sure I'm doing something silly, but I can't for the life of me figure it out!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Using htmlpurifier-4.4.0-lite with PHP 5.3.14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off magic quotes. See the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: @edward-z-yang If it run phpinfo(), it looks like magic quotes are already off: `magic_quotes_gpc: Off, magic_quotes_runtime: Off, magic_quotes_sybase: Off` Or is there another place I need to check to see if it is set to on?  Thanks

Comment: Are you MySQL escaping the string before passing it to HTML Purifier? What does it look like before you pass it to HTML Purifier?

Comment: That was it - my quotes were being escaped before being passed to HTML Purifier.  I can't believe I missed it, but thanks so much for the help.